# How to manage facebook page using php sdk

Tags: facebook-page

I am a new beginner for Facebook apps
I want to manage Facebook pages using php code.
For that i have created a Facebook application

Now i need to get some info or sample code for managing Facebook pages using that application.

What i understood that I need to set my application permissions for that 
i have set my Facebook application permissions for that

but not getting how to start

any help or sample code will be very very thankful.

regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Only one of the page admins can grant your app access to do things on behalf of the page (there is one exception, and that is when the page was created using a username/password directly rather than by a normal facebook user).  For how to authenticate them see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/  And then pay attention to the part that talks about /me/accounts.

Comment: hmmm i have got the list of my pages , but now don't know how to manipulate them , can you help on this please :)

Comment: Now, just use that access token from the page you find in the list for your API calls.

Comment: can you provide any link to show how i need to make an api call to add a tab in facebook page using php